# GtK+ endless reinstallation loop on MacOS Ventura (13.2.1)

Tags: macos, gtk, apple-silicon, rattle

Old discussions elided as I'd think stuff will have changed a lot.
OS X Ventural 13.2.1
[R.app GUI 1.79 (8160) aarch64-apple-darwin20] (just downloaded from:
)
Fresh installation, open the R.app, at the R console

```
library(rattle)
rattle()
```

Every time I start, it reprompts for installing GTK2 (see above) ... quitting and restarting causes that to happen again ... and again... clearly, something is not taking ... pointers to the many fine manuals appreciated.

As above, installed, load the rattle library, authorize the reinstallation of GTK+, loop forever.

Comment: First instinct would be it's installing an x86_64 library, fails to load it into an arm64 process, rinse and repeat. But this sounds like it should be a bug report to whoever maintains that.

Comment: Well, since the library has been withdrawn ... it no longer has a maintainer, everyone was supposed to migrate off of it ;<

A relatively easy hack is leverage the docker kanyon/rattle image. Assuming Xquarts and docker already installed, and having fixed one's .ssh/config to permit X11 forwarding, then, from an XQuartz/xterm 

docker run -it --rm -e DISPLAY=$ip:0.0 --platform linux/amd64    kayon/rattle

The right fix would be to wean Rattle from obsolete dependencies (cario, RGtk2, ?) but that's a non-trivial effort, I'm sure.